# Is there a way when using pd.read_csv to get type of value datetime.datetime not timestamp?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

When I using parse_dates in read_csv, the type of date col is loaded as timestamp.
I want a  datetime.datetime object, not a timestamp.
Is there any way?
Do I need to convert from timestamp to  datetime.datetime?

Comment: Could you please provide an example of the input, and the code you use to process it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to convert `timestamp` to `datetime`:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], unit='s')
```

If the timestamp shows the datetime as seconds use unit='s'. Otherwise:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], infer_datetime_format=True)
```

Comment: It is not working.. still timestamp

Comment: check the updated solution